# How to solve Warning Invalid prop `color` of value `inherit` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextField)`, expected one of ["primary","secondary"]

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, mui

I am getting this warning

**Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `inherit` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextField)`, expected one of ["primary","secondary"].**

I tried changing the color from **inherit** to **primary** and changed
and also I have changed
**import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';** 
 to   **import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';** still the error remains same

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the dependencY file  to work for me, I changed the package.json from

"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.6.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",}

to 
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "~4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",}
now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue caused by a recent update to Material-ui module. 
This worked for me https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1293#issuecomment-558972419